# Приложение никогда не попадает в раздел "популярные" в gnome-меню

Tags: linux, gnome

Создал в `~/local/share/applications` .desktop файл такого содержания:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Haven and Hearth
Comment=HnH Amber Client
Exec=/home/winterwolf/soft/haven/amber/run.sh
Icon=/home/winterwolf/soft/haven/haven-icon.png
Path=/home/winterwolf/soft/haven/amber
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Game;
```

Этот файл запускает java-игру через баш-скрипт. Вот так выглядит скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Djogl.disable.opengles=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar hafen.jar -U http://game.havenandhearth.com/hres/ game.havenandhearth.com
```

Теперь, когда я открываю меню со всеми приложениями, я вижу "ярлык" в разделе с играми и он запускается. Всё работает как и положено, но я играю в эту игру каждый день больше месяца и она ни разу не попадала в раздел "популярные", хотя стоит мне установить что угодно, запустить пару раз и оно сразу же появляется там. В чём может быть причина и как это исправить?